# ecs in java : how to enjoy cache Friendly？

Tags: java, entity-component-system

the reason **ECS** (entity component system) has great performance, like **entitas** in unity, is that components of same type are put in the same memory chunk, which make component iterating fast and efficient.

However, in java we cannot manage object memory location, so **ecs** seems
to be not so useful as **c++** in java language. Is that true, or actually there is some way to realize **cache friendly ecs** in java?

Comment: Did you search the web for articles, blog posts, and github repos around ECS for Java, first? There's quite a few if my casual googling is any indication.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans there are some ecs framework for java. But none of them has mentioned the cache friendliness problem. Those frameworks seem to just imitate the design patten of **ecs**, without implementing  the biggest benifit of perfomance in **ecs**

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you don't have value-type objects yet (see [Project Valhalla](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/))
This means that you won't create an array of objects in the same chunk, but this doesn't mean you cannot have an ECS for Java with performance comparable with ECS for C / C++.
In this regard, I have already started an ECS [project](https://github.com/dominion-dev/dominion-ecs-java) in Java 17 which aims to demonstrate similar performance against system languages and shows benchmarks that look very promising.

Comment: but how could you achieve perfomance promote without value-type objects?